# How to resole a dependency using the consuming class metadata

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

The setup is below, I want `IDependency` used by `Service` to be created with `attachedToClassName = nameof(Service)` or indeed the actual class name, consuming `IDependency`.

I can't change constructors / interfaces, I'm looking for a solution working with .NET Core DI (no side libs).

```
public class OtherDependency: IOtherDependency
{
  
}

public class Dependency: IDependency
{
   public Dependency(IOtherDependency otherDependency, string attachedToClassName) {...}
}

public class Service
{
   // 
   public Service(IDependency dependency)
   {
      
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the better approach would be the same .net core uses for ILogger -> introducing the generic type. This means you should change your interfaces and you don't want to.

Let's dive in the difficult one.

We need to take a look at this method:

```
 ObjectFactory ActivatorUtilitiess.CreateFactory(Type, Type[])
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

This method returns an object factory for the type given as first parameter.
ObjectFactory is a delegate:

```
public delegate object ObjectFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, object[] arguments);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.objectfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

than we also need this overload of IServiceCollection.AddSingleton (or wathever lifetime)

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddSingleton(this IServiceCollection services, Type serviceType, Func<IServiceProvider, object> factory)
```

in your Startup.ConfigureServices you should the following:

```
 var objFactory1 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(Dependency1), new Type[]{typeof(string)});
 var objFactory2 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(Dependency2), new Type[]{typeof(string)});
 //and so on for all your concrete dependencies

 var serviceObjFactory1 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(Service1), new Type[] {typeof(IDependency)});

 services.AddSingleton(typeof(Service1),sp => serviceObjFactory1(sp, new object[] {
     objFactory1(sp, new object[]{"attached for Service1"})
 });
```

with the object factory you instantiate a class that retrieves all the dependency from the service provider except the dependencies of the types you specified when you created the factory. Those dependencies instances must be given when you invoke the factory

Comment: This means you should change your interfaces and you want to. - *I don't*. Please don't post if you don't have a solution. I appreciate your effort, I know how to do it with autofac, but I want to en-devour the .net core way if it exists. Thanks. -

Comment: sorry I meant you don't want to, please read until the end :)